# Trouble clicking on a next-page button with webscraping (Selenium)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to webscrape this page https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos-publicacion-menor-a-7-dias.html. However, I'm having trouble clicking on the next-page button to scrape all the pages. I've tried doing this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
wd = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)
wd.maximize_window()

wd.get("https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos-publicacion-menor-a-7-dias.html")

def pag_sig():
    element_present = EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="Pagination__NextPage-sc-el3mid-4 gSlsBf"]/i'))
    boton = WebDriverWait(wd,5).until(element_present)
    boton.click()

page_max=127 #I get this with another piece of code
for i in range(page_max):
    pag_sig()
```

However, this does not work properly. Sometimes my scraper clicks on other links rather than the button itself. I've tried adding waits but it doesn't work. How could I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May its because of not scrolling down. Try the below xpath and code once.

```
#xpath - //div[@id='listado-avisos']//button[@class='Pagination__NextPage-sc-el3mid-4 gSlsBf']

driver.get("https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos-publicacion-menor-a-7-dias.html")
for i in range (5):
    nextoption = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='listado-avisos']//button[@class='Pagination__NextPage-sc-el3mid-4 gSlsBf']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", nextoption)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,-300)")
    nextoption.click()
    time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the button instead of directly clicking on the `i` below can help, I hope

```
  button = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='Pagination__NextPage-sc-el3mid-4 gSlsBf']")))

    button.click()
```